# Error message while installing Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

I downloaded [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi) [7.0.22], and tried to install it. I am getting the following Error Message;

> Failed to install Tomcat7 service.
>
> Check your settings and permissions.
>
> Ignore and continue anyway (not recommended)?

What is this and how do i resolve it?

Comment: Which operating system? Did you use the installer or the ZIP file?

Comment: Windows Vista, and i downloaded the installer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Tomcat web server will run as service in the background. This requires administrator rights.

Comment: Yes, and if that's not what you need, just run it yourselve, the startup script is in tomcat_home\bin